# hide/suppress parts of a (iframed) google form

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-forms

I'm using the iframe-html-element to show a Google Form within my app. Can anyone give me some tips on how to hide/suppress parts of that form? e.g. header, footer, etc. specifically I want to hide the `<div class="ss-header-image"></div>` and `<div class="ss-top-of-page">` and `<div class="ss-legal">` and `<div class="ss-password-warning ss-secondary-text">`

ps my app is a combination of html, css & javascript, including jquery.

Comment: You want to remove the warning about submitting passwords? That sounds… evil.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the other site wants to co-operate and add some JS to listen for requests from `postMessage`, you cannot.

It is Goggle's page, you cannot change it.